# GET form in PHP. How to link to the 2nd+ page of results?

Tags: php, forms, post, get, pagination

I have a `POST` form in PHP that I'm converting to `GET`.

The form works and gives me the first page of results without any problems.

But how do I link to the second page?  I assume I have to replicate all the `GET` parameters into the "Next Page" link plus the page number (which the script already handles), but how would I do that?

**CLARIFICATION:**  How do I get all the `GET` variables from a form onto a link in the page?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Think about your problem more and provide some sample code in addition to more details about what the page does. Perhaps also choose a different username.

Comment: @Xeoncross, I was purposefully vague because the existing POST script already works, but I'm just changing the `action` of the form to `GET` and I just need figure out how to get the `GET` parameters from the URL onto a link.  That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simpliest way is too to do something like:

```
$get = preg_replace("/page=\d+/i", "", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$link = "somepage.php?".$get."&page=".($_GET['page']+1);

echo "<a href='".$link."'>Next Page</a>";
```

That will simply take the get string, remove the page then add the page back in as +1. Please note this would be insecure as people could pass anything in the query string. A better option would be to build the the URL explicitly by checking for each expected $_GET key=>value pair, validating it, then adding it to a link variable. That way any additional bits in the query string wont be echo'd to the page.

EDIT:

Ok so heres a very quick example.

```
$category = (int)$_GET['cat'];
$keyword = trim($_GET['keyword']);
$keyword = filter_var($keyword, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


$nextlink  = "somepage.php?";
$nextlink .= http_build_query(array(
   "cat" => $category,
   "keyword" => $keyword,
   "page" => $page+1
));
```

So basically you get the GET var's you want, validate them, then just use http_build_query and an associative array to build your query string for the link. The security i put in their is very basic, but typecasting numbers and limiting the amount of crud you can stick into a string is a place to start

Comment: Is checking for each expected $_GET key=>value pair standard way to do the pagination on a $_GET form?

Comment: depends what you class as standard. but generally speaking it is yes. Some more complex scripts may use a search class that grabs all the $_GET's it needs to do its stuff, validates them and then has a method to create the links. That appears more seamless but essentially is the same thing.

You could build your own automation method where you can pass the GET keys you want and some instructions as to the allowed data in them. But if its just for one form i wouldn't bother making it that complex.

I'll added a simple example above of the easiest approach for you

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically speaking, you would read them out of the request like this:

```
$link = 'mypage/?someitem=' . $_GET['someitem'] . '&amp;page=' . ($page + 1);
```

Although you may not wish to trust the parameters as they may contain an HTML injection or other nasty tricks designed to attack your website.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just `URL?param1=val1&param2=val2&...`?

Comment: Yes, but how would you access all the params and vals to build the link?